# What is the name for a reaction with a solid product rising from its container?

Tags: terminology

The [reaction between sugar and sulfuric acid](http://www.rsc.org/education/eic/issues/2007March/ExhibitionChemistry.asp) is well known to produce a solid column of rising carbon which may leave its container.  A very similar rising column may also be produced from high temperature pyrolysis of certain organic substrates.

Is there a name exclusive to the type of reaction that produces a rising column?

Comment: One of my buddies poured himself a beer.  Beer going into the glass caused a frothing reaction.  Has anyone heard of solid frothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pyrotechnic chemistry, they might call it a pharoh's snake (or serpent) reaction. To a degree, (or rather 330 °C) pyrolysis of the sugar is occurring (starting at 170 °C).

In cooking, they would call it [caramelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramelization), although the term is also applicable in general chemistry. Less specifically, you can call it a "browning reaction"... note- caramelization (non-enzymatic) should not be confused with a [Maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) (enzymatic). More specifically, you could call it dehydration or decomposition of sugar with sulfuric acid. Somewhere in-between you might find the term [carbonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonization).

You may also find the terms [carbon soufflé](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCex0EVnvu0) and [carbon foam](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008622315001098) interesting.

Comment: Ok, that is the detailed Dad answer. Mom's more to point answer is - No. There is no specific name for such a reaction.

Comment: @MaxW Ha, you got me!

Comment: Plus there are also a number of names referring to the fact that it is something cylindric and it is rising.

Comment: While doing biochar research, sometimes this reaction happens instead of char formation.  I was hoping for something more scientific sounding than a d*** mess, which is what I was calling it. This answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrated sulfuric acid [dehydrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydration_reaction) almost any hydroxyl containing organic molecule. This is the specific type of reaction that is occurring.

The reason the carbon-column forms  is the intense heat that is released from the reaction. The water vaporizes and rises, carrying the carbon with it.

Comment: Dehydration does not always form a rising column (example  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhE6CM6Qbws.)  Certain pyrolytic reactions do form a rising column.  I am looking for a name describing a reaction which produces this phenomena.

Comment: That is a completely different type of dehydration. The dehydration reaction that I was talking about specifically involves the removal of water from an organic compound, not the driving off of water from a hydrated salt.

Comment: Is there a name for this specific form of dehydration?

Comment: I believe it would be called acid catalyzed dehydration.

Comment: I changed the language in the question for clarity.

Comment: How about "Charring"?